# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Java on getting sub string

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to divide a list of string in chunks ,hence I have written this method ,

```
public static List<List<String>> chunkIds(List<String> ids,
        int max) {
    List<List<String>> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i = i + max) {
        List<String> chunk = ids.subList(i, i + max);
        chunks.add(chunk);
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

when I call the method
I get IndexOutOfBoundsException on getting the subList .where max is a chunk size  .Could someone please help me understand the index logic wrong here.

Comment: Well, assume you have 6 items in the `ids` list and `max` is 3. Then when you get to `i=4`, you're trying to get items 4 through 7. But the list only has items 0 through 5.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes I get it now , when i + max is more than ids size , the toIndex should be set to ids size. thanks

Comment: @RealSkeptic i can never be 4 because it is always a multiple of 3 in your example. But if he has 7 or 8 items, he will get the exception when i=6. -> @ Hmahwish ever tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @DanielAlder I understood my logical error here .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `i + max` as the second parameter to `subList`, if `ids.size()` isn't exactly divisible by `max`, that index will be greater than `ids.size()`.

Use

```
Math.min(i + max, ids.size())
```

instead of `i + max`.

Or, avoiding calculating the `min` each time:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i + max < ids.size(); i += max) {
  chunks.add(ids.subList(i, i + max));
}
if (i < ids.size()) {
  chunks.add(ids.subList(i, ids.size());
}
```

Comment: I got the logical error now , to set the to index size to ids.size if its less than max. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> chunk = ids.subList(i, i + max);
```

what is `max`? `i + max` should not be greater than `ids.size()`

Comment: @Daniel Alder Thanks